# Heroku still redirects to https

Tags: python, django, ssl, heroku, https

I removed SSL from our site a couple of days ago and have faced a lot of problems. However, most of them have been solved and only one exist: one gets redirected to https even though you put in http.

In Heroku I've removed the SSL app as well as the pointers in PointDNS that pointed to osaka-4635.herokussl.com.

As for now I have the following in PointDNS:

- NS pointers from root to dns**x**.pointhq.com
- ALIAS from root to heroku app
- CNAME from www to heroku app

Is something wrong here or may it be something in the backend code that needs to be changed?
May the problem be at our DNS provider instead of Heroku?

Again, all I want i to remove https.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Searched in project folder for 'https' and found it in several files where our web adress is hard coded (https://www.sitename/...) so I understand that all of this needs to be changed to http. Except for that I found it in the following files (followed by the code).

*middleware.py*:

```
class RequestSSLMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if not any((DEBUG, request.is_secure(), request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', '') == 'https')):
            url = request.build_absolute_uri(request.get_full_path())
            secure_url = url.replace('http://', 'https://')
            return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(secure_url)

class ResponseSSLMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if not DEBUG:
            if 'Location' in response:
                if response['Location'][0] == '/':
                    response['Location'] = 'https://' + get_current_site(request).domain + response['Location']
        return response
```

*settings_base.py*:

```
# Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

*gunicorn.conf*:

```
secure_scheme_headers = {
    'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https'
}
```

*settings.py:*

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

**I guess I have some work in front of me... but for those of you that understands the code, may it be lots of work to change from https to http in this case?**

Comment: check your htaccess. and if there's nothing in there, it might be a code that rewrites the `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`.

Comment: @Deer-Outdoor.nl: Thanks. Is there a specific file I should be looking at for this line of code?

Comment: In your htaccess look for something with https rewrite, and in code look for something that checks if $_SERVER['HTTPS'] is http and redirects it to https.

Comment: @Deer-Outdoor.nl: Searched through all files for $_SERVER['HTTPS'] but no match, so I guess I'll have to check htaccess. Where can I find/access this file (again, I'm on Heroku with python/django)?

Comment: Search for something like `server {
   listen 80;
   rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
}` in your code. And htaccess is in root of the website mostly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locate MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in settings.py or settings_base.py, and comment the lines containing "RequestSSLMiddleware" and "ResponseSSLMiddleware". These are custom middleware classes, not provided by Django.

Comment the line containing SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER in settings.py, not needed anymore since you don't want https.